# Network Printer is not included on Win32_Printer after publishing the Web Application

Tags: vb.net

This is my Sample code , I retrieve the IP Address of the client's PC and get all the installed local and network Pinter .
`

```
        Dim scope As New ManagementScope($"\\{HostIP}\root\cimv2")
        Dim query As New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")
        Dim Search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)
        Dim printers As ManagementObjectCollection = Search.Get()

        '---------------Geting All Printer-------------------------     
        DT = New DataTable
        With DT
            .Columns.Add("Printer", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        End With

        For Each printer As ManagementObject In printers
            Dim Another1 As PropertyDataCollection = printer.Properties
            Dim PCheck As String = ""
            For Each Another2 As PropertyData In Another1
                If CBool(printer("Network")) Then
                    If printer(Another2.Name) IsNot Nothing AndAlso printer(Another2.Name).ToString().Contains("\\192.168.1.9\") Then
                        If printer(Another2.Name) <> PCheck Then
                            DT.Rows.Add(printer(Another2.Name))
                            PCheck = printer(Another2.Name)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            Dim Check As String = printer("Name").ToString()
            If Not Check.Contains("Microsoft") Then
                If CBool(printer("Local")) Then
                    DT.Rows.Add(Check)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ds.Tables.Add(DT)`
```

I already tried that code in my localhost and it get all Printers,
[Local Host Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcE9E.png)
but after deploying it on the website it doesn't get the network Printers only Local Printer
[Website Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO1GT.png)

Can anyone help me.